# Express one set in a partition through the others

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=A\cup B\cup C$, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are mutually disjoint.
Clearly, $C=S-(A\cup B)=(A\cup B)^c$. How do we derive this identity? Or it's supposed to be obvious (and it is) from the fact that ${A, B, C}$ is a partition of $S$?

It's used in my textbook but the author never mentioned where it came from.

Comment: See [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set):  it comes from the definition.

Comment: Is it really need $A$ separate from $B$?

Comment: You should use a Venn diagram. It should be clear from it. When you draw it, identify $A\cup B$ and see how it relates to $C$.

Comment: @zkutch rright. Suppose $x\in C$. Then $x\in S$ and $x\notin (A\cup B)$. Therefore $x\in S-(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 0):

For sets $D,C$ we have $$[D \cap C = \emptyset] \Leftrightarrow \left[ (D \cup C) \setminus C = D \right]$$

Now we can take $D=A \cup B$